# Vega lite - accessing 'repeat' variable to use as filter

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm attempting to make a trellis bar chart, with the grand total shown faintly behind each chart - see this image.

[image]

I've successfully managed to create this a verbose spec, but I want to make this more succinct, by using 'repeat' with a filter.  [Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/vega-lite/robinl/954d2118eecd41bbf9b5a342e195476d/73175bd101881ecb0e9eb17ff7ab9580cd8abcea/done.json) is the working version.

[Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/vega-lite/robinl/4fe9c4635fbc15d18b697d96816c2aef/c648be1dae06bf9ca329ab126601ede45502706c/almost_works.json) is my version which almost works, but I can't work out how to allow the filter to access the 'repeat' variable.

How can I access the variable specified in 'repeat' to correctly filter the data?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
 { 
  "transform": [
     {"filter": "datum.gender == repeat"}
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported right now: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/2518. These kinds of use cases where you can reuse parts will work much better in DSLs like Altair. JSON is unfortunately not a good fit for reuse. As a side note, a succinct spec is not faster than the verbose spec you wrote. However, I understand that it would be easier to read. Another related proposal for shorter specs is: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3384.